# Python : TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I am newbie programmer trying to make an irc bot that parse xml and paste its content on a channel. Usually i find my answer on google, but this time i can't find my answer.

```
q0tag = dom.getElementsByTagName('hit')[0].toxml()
q0 = q0tag.replace('<hit>','').replace('</hit>','')

q1 = (q0 * 1.2)
```

when i'm trying to multiply q0 it always showing

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.
```

Im trying to make q0 int or float but it just make another error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

q0 value is a round number without decimal.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your q0 value is still a string. This is basically what you're doing:

```
>>> q0 = '3'
>>> q1 = (q0 * 1.2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

To fix it, convert the string to a number first:

```
>>> q1 = (float(q0) * 1.2)
>>> q1
3.5999999999999996
```

You might also want to look into the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) modules for parsing XML.

Comment: +1 for mentioning XML parsers. [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) are also pretty nice.

Comment: I did at first, but removed it. I realized OP is using ``xml.dom`` which is probably okay

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too just after I commented. I'll keep the links there anyway because somebody might find them useful.

Answer (score 2):

`Toxml()` produces string (see e.g. http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html). `Replace` also produces a string, so `q0` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while using the Manim library. My issue was this line in the `x_axis_config` dict:

```
 "label_direction": [ 0, -1, 0],
```

The correct usage looks something like this:

```
"label_direction": DOWN,
```